# My prompt won't return a string, it only returns NaN

Tags: javascript, nan, prompt

I'm quite new to this and cannot understand what is going on.

My code is as follows:

```
let p = prompt("Enter your name, please", "");
let o = prompt("Enter your age, please.", "");
let fname = parseInt(p);
let age = parseInt(o);
let year = (2018 - age);
document.getElementById("p1");
p1.innerHTML = fname + ", you were born in " + year;
```

When all the is entered on the browser, I end up with something that reads:

"NaN, you were born in 1990"

The number part works, but the string doesn't.

Comment: Welcome to SO... you shouldn't use `parseInt()` on a text... and that should fix it.

Comment: `NaN` = "Not a Number"

Comment: Quick tip: This will give the incorrect birth year for anyone whose birthday has not yet come within the current calendar year. Checkout Date constructor to level up and improve your app. :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: A great example of what happens when you copy-paste code without understanding what it does.

Answer (score 4):

You're running parseInt() on your first name field. Just remove that parseInt call since your name is not an integer!

Comment: Well that was easy... thank you very much!